# Devise can't find user by email even though email is in DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a rails app using Devise for authentication.

I have a user (User@yahoo.com.mx note capital U) who is failing to sign in because Devise can't find him. He tried to register and devise says that the email is already taken. It's pretty strange.

I imagine this is either because of the capital letter or the double domain? Probably the capital (user registered when we were using a different registration system many years ago).

What is going on here and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Capitalization shouldn't be causing an issue.  If the email is already taken, but the user is unable to register (or sign in), they probably created an account with that email address, but the account is not yet `active`.

You probably have a module enabled in Devise that requires the user to be 'activated' somehow (e.g. [confirmable](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb)).

You need to either:

- Have the user take action to activate their account (like if they need to confirm their email address by clicking on a link that was sent to their email), or. . .
- Use the console to enable the user (e.g. `User.find_by!(email: 'User@yahoo.com.mx').confirm`).